# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './factoryWithThrowingShims' in 'C:\Myproject\prop-types'

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I have a React project that has been running for some time, and building OK.

I recently added another library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-shielded), and my build no longer works with the error :

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './factoryWithThrowingShims' in 'C:\Myproject\prop-types'
```

In my project, I am not using prop-types at all (I am using Typescript), but I assume that other projects have some sort of dependency on them. For what it's worth, I checked the react-shielded project, and they themselves are not using prop-types, but I assume some other dependency is.

When I yarn add this library, I can see in my lock file the following change :

[image]

So adding this library does add another dependency on prop-types. I have tried cleaning cache, wiping the node_modules folder, and even deleting the lock file to see if that resolves it but it doesn't. So I assume that there is some sort of dependency issue with possibly my version of React, and what this library is using.

From my package.json, React is set to : ^18.2.0.